# Security Alert: Vulnerable Package 'nth-check' in Vercel-hosted Web Apps

Tags: github, security, npm, dependencies, vercel

I recently started receiving a security alert in my GitHub repositories for web apps hosted on Vercel. The alert is related to a vulnerable package called 'nth-check,' which is used in my TikTok UI clone project. The security alert mentions that 'nth-check' has an issue with "Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity," and it has a high severity level with a CVSS base score of 7.5 out of 10 (CVE ID: CVE-2021-3803).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5xYS.png)

I have tried various solutions to address the security vulnerability:

1. Attempted automatic updates using Dependabot, but it couldn't update 'nth-check' to a non-vulnerable version due to conflicting dependencies.
2. Manually updated 'nth-check' to version 2.0.1 in the package-lock.json file, but it caused compatibility issues with other dependencies and broke the project.
3. Checked for updates in other dependencies, but couldn't find a resolution for the conflict with 'nth-check@2.0.1' and 'react-scripts@5.0.1.'

What I Expected:
I expected to find a solution to resolve the security vulnerability in 'nth-check' while keeping the project running smoothly on Vercel. However, all the attempted solutions resulted in issues with either compatibility or a persistent security alert.

Before posting, I have reviewed questions already on Stack Overflow to see if there's a similar issue, but I haven't found one specifically related to the conflict between 'nth-check@2.0.1' and 'react-scripts@5.0.1' in Vercel-hosted web apps.

I appreciate any insights, suggestions, or workarounds to address this security vulnerability while maintaining the stability of my web app on Vercel. Thank you in advance for your help!